# pointer to array of multiple elements that can be anything including string,or function pointers

Tags: c

If I have pointer-to-array of `multiple pointers` to char

for example if I declare it and allocate it like

```
   char *(*tags)[2] = malloc (20 * sizeof *tags);
```

so in above line I am creating pointer 'to array ' of pairs which can either be of data type `int` or `char` or something. so for example if I like to have each three-object-pairs list like `{{"<html","</html>",my_function},{"<head","</head>",my_func_2}}` where `my_function` and `my_func_2` are functions then is it doable somehow. if it can't be done with above then what will be needed so what are array of pointers to pointers or something to achieve this. I hope if I made sense I can explain more

Comment: Why not create a struct, like `struct Tag {const char *begin, *end; ... func;};`, then create an array of those?

Comment: Or don't use struct. Why not this?